# json ajax complex type pass to MVC2 action

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-2, model

I know this has been asked before in a similar form, but I have hit a bit of problem here....
I have this classic problem of trying to pass a json complex type to MVC2.
The problem (refer to the code below): I can pass the value "subincidentID" to the controller but the values "CodeType", "MOCode" and "SubCode" are all NULL.
I HAVE installed the MVC2 future and registered "Microsoft.Web.MVC" in global.asax.cs and declare the JsonValueProviderFactory.

The JQuery bit:

```
$('#btnDone').click(function() {
        var entity = {};
        var dbCode = new Array();
        dbCode[0] = { CodeType: "1", MoCode: "13", SubCode: "12" };
        entity = { subincidentID: "1", codeData: dbCode };      
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: entity,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                url: "/controller/SaveMOData",
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('success!');
                }
            }); //end of post
        });   //end of btnDone click function
```

Controller in MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveMOData(MOSubMitModel mo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            return Json(new { success = "true" });
        }
```

Model class in MVC (2):

```
public class MOSubMitModel
    {
        public int subIncidentID { get; set; }
        public List<dbCode> codeData { get; set; }
    }

    public class dbCode
    {
        public string CodeType { get; set; }
        public string subCode { get; set; }
        public string MoCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Have I missed something here?
Do I have to declare any namespace on the controller page?
I am sure it is a small problem but I have been scratching my head the whole day about it....:-(..

Thanks in advance.
W. Lam

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of issues using the following syntax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {prop:"Value"},
    ....
}
```

Instead you need to stringify the object

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({prop:"Value"}),
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I was going to edit my question with the stringify function because it did not work before (all returned NULL) but I have actually figured it out myself....will post the answer in the next post...

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial-and-error and readings I have finally figured it out myself (Refer to the previous posting for details of the other components):

```
$('#btnDone').click(function() {
        :
        :
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(entity),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            url: "/controller/SaveMOData",
            success: function(result) {
                alert('success!');
            }
        }); //end of post
    });   //end of btnDone click function
```

The problem was me NOT to include "contentType" (I had tried to inclide json stringify before but it ALL returns NULL if I do not include contentType)...so...to summarise the requirements under MVC2:

Download [MVC Future](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) .....Unzip the MVC future zip file and copy Microsoft.web.mvc to your project, and reference it In your project's global.asax.cs file, include the "Microsoft.web.mvc" namespace, and then include the following line at the end of the function "Application_start"

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Make the necessary changes in your jQuery as indicated above.  It should be working (well it works for me!!)..Hope it helps anyone with the same problem.